# what version of safari is the iphone os using? (as of 12/14/2009)

Tags: iphone, html, safari, canvas

What version of Safari is on the iphone now?  Is it Safari 4?  Safari 3?  2?  Something in between?  In other words, when I'm writing code for the iphone, which version of Safari for the pc/mac will be the most accurate version to test it with?

I think I've already run into a case where the canvas tag is handled differently on the iphone than it is in safari 4.  (specifically the fillText javascript cmd doesn't seem to work).

Comment: When you went to Apple's iPhone SDK site, what did they say?  Please provide a link to their information to make the question reasonably complete.

Answer (score 6):

Point your iPhone here, the link provided by Neil doesn't seem to be working for me.
[Link](http://www.systemdetails.com/browser.php)

Update.
I accessed the website with my itouch and this is the response:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (ipod: U;CPU iPhone OS 2_2 like Mac OS X: es_es) AppleWebKit/525.18.1
Browser Name/Version: M_webkit/3.1.1
```

So I'm assuming it's safari 3.1.1

Comment: Are you sure your iPod Touch is running the very latest OS version?

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure It's running the very latest OS version.
But it was purchased just a few months ago and it's the best and most informative answer I can give him.

Comment: From here: http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3 , that user agent string would seem to indicate iPhone OS 2.x (also, the iPhone OS 2_2 should be a clue).  My iPhone running OS 3.1.2 responds with AppleWebKit/528.18 Version/4.0 Mobile/7D11 Safari/528.16.

Comment: There are subtle differences, but iPhone OS 3.0 shares much in common with Snow Leopard.  We were told that iPhone OS 3.0's mobile Safari was based around Safari 4.0, although there are a few elements that are slightly different.

Comment: So based on these last comments here, it looks like it is "Safari 4 Mobile" or, in other words, a mobile version of Safari 4.  It'd be nice if it had full support of the canvas tag's text rendering capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should test your project with the iPhone simulator and on the actual devices you are preparing to deploy to.

As you mentioned, testing on a different platform is a guaranteed headache.

Comment: I'm effectively trying to find out if the Safari on mac or pc is acceptable to develop against (for the most part) because I can't seem to find a webkit dom reference that is for the mobile version of Safari, specifically.  Also, I don't always have a mac at my finger tips when I have a little bit of coding time.

Answer (score 0):

Just do google as "show user agent"

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=show+user+agent

**Output**

it shows my browser version *firefox 54.0*

[image]